# I'm coding for the function to see the Faculty's details and it shows number of majors of that faculty. How to count array with in template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

> I'm coding for the function to see the Faculty's details and it shows number of majors of that faculty. I don't know how to count array majors with v-if and v-for. Please help me fix that. Many thanks.

**Template tag**

```
<tr>
    <td>Sumary: 
        <strong v-for="major in majors">
            <strong v-if="form.faculty_code==majors.major_faculty">
             {{ major }}
            </strong>
        </strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Script tag**

```
data() {
    return {
        faculties:[],
        majors:[],
        form: new Form({
            faculty_id:'',
            faculty_code:'',
            faculty_name:'',
            faculty_status: '',
        }),
    };
}, 
mounted() {
    this.fetchMajors();
    this.fetchFaculties();
},
methods: {
    fetchFaculties(page_url) {
        let vm = this;
        page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-faculty/faculty/'+this.currentEntries+'?page='+this.pagination.current_page;
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.faculties = res.data;
            this.pagination = res.meta;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },    
    fetchMajors(page_url) {
        let vm = this;
        page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-major/chuyen-nganh/major';
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.majors = res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
}
```

Comment: You dont need v-for, you can just use majors.length in html / this.majors.length in script

Comment: @Friedrich how can i compare major_faculty at tbl_major with faculty_code at table tbl_faculty to get the total count?

Comment: How is this question related to MySQL and Laravel? You haven't shared any code related to these two techniques

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry for my wrong tagging, because i'm working on a project related to laravel mysql and vue so i tagged by mistake. Sorry again for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get the amount of majors with the given faculty code you can use in your mounted() function

```
this.total.majors = 0;
this.majors.forEach((element) => {
    element.major_faculty == this.faculty_code ? this.total_majors += 1  : ""
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for watching and help me. I've found the solution for this.

**Template tag**

```
<tr>
<td>Sumary: 
    <strong>
        {{ countA.length }}
    </strong>
</td>
```

**Script tag**

```
computed: {
        countA() {
            return this.majors.filter(major => major.major_faculty==this.form.faculty_code);
        }
    },
```